# LUIS not able to classify multiple person names in a query

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am having an issue where in LUIS is unable to identify multiple person names in an utterance when separated by **"and or ,"** in a phrase.

For Eg:
When user types, "Schedule a meeting with Bob and Lisa", LUIS recognizes only Bob as builtin.personName where in Lisa is not recognized at all. Also separating names with comma didn't work either. If I change the order of names to Lisa and Bob, only Lisa gets listed and poor Bob gets ignored this time.

Also it failed to identify the name when typing, "Book meeting and Bob".

My another attempt was successful after changing the utterance to "Book meeting with Bob as well as Lisa". But that would not be general way of posting a query.

Phrase lists didn't help either, I have added below two samples in phrase list but the results were same as stated above.
"Schedule a meeting with {personName}, {personName}"
"can i have {personName} and {personName} for a quick meeting"

I don't see similar issue with emails separated by "and or comma".

Note:I also tried built in domain entity Entertainment.Person but got similar results.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your app more intelligent by adding patterns to the app. I have tried to replicate your issue by creating my LUIS app, it successfully detects the entities properly. Refer the app stored as a gist here : https://gist.github.com/mandardhikari/f0edd9406aeeb6d7b9fd0f68371ff4eb